# Test behaves differently in workspace than as standalone project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Why would a test pass when included in a workspace, but fail when I move the entire directory out of the workspace. Everything builds correctly in both contexts, but the code behaves differently in the two cases, and so the test fails in the standalone project.

The workspace in question is this one: https://github.com/amethyst/rustrogueliketutorial

The project in the workspace is `chapter-07-damage`.

I can include the test, if necessary, but I'm mostly trying to understand what extra context is used in the workspace that causes the code to behave so differently.

Thanks, all!

Comment: If you take the time to make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, chances are high you will figure out the solution yourself.

Comment: I have, and I didn't. The "minimal" example is still pretty big, but it can be found here: https://github.com/gmadrid/trgl-ws.

The test in the trgl subdir fails both as a standalone and in the workspace. However, if I move trgl into the rustrogueliketutorial workspace, the test passes. 

Again, I am trying to understand what context may be coming from the workspace that is causing the behavior change.

Comment: The link you gave goes to an empty repository. Also, I looked at `chapter-07-damage` in the original workspace and didn't see any test code in that directory. I recommend editing your question to explain what you're observing in much more detail than "a test fails".